# How to isomorphically handle subdomain with react + router + redux?

Tags: react-router, react-redux, isomorphic-javascript, react-router-redux

I'm building a service where other companies can host a community at `companyname.mydomain.com`. I have a Redux reducer called `company` that holds certain state about that company. I'd like to be able to isomorphically fetch data about that company based on the subdomain requested.

If I have a function `getSubdomain`:

```
function getSubdomain(host) {
  const hostWithoutPort = host.split(':')[0];
  return hostWithoutPort.split('.').slice(0, -2).join('.');
}
```

Then on the client I'd get the subdomain by doing:

```
const subdomain = getSubdomain(window.location.host);
```

On the server, since window isn't available and the host is different per request, I'd do:

```
const subdomain = getSubdomain(request.headers.host);
```

What's the right strategy to properly isomorphically fetch company data based on this subdomain? I'm thinking maybe I could initialize my store with the subdomain set in the state?

Comment: Not sure what the correct tag is here, sorry if the router tags are irrelevant. :/

Comment: what are you using under the hood to process requests? express?

Comment: @lfender6445: vanilla node